# What does "241 on one" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> In 2008, a remote Russian missile station was overwhelmed and held for
> a week. When the station was retaken, **[241](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plutonium-241) on one** warhead was three
> quarters of a kilo lighter. The missing [241](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plutonium-241) surfaced at the opera
> house siege in Kiev on the 14th.

What does "241 on one" mean?

Source: Christopher Nolan's movie [*Tenet* (2020)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tenet_(film))

Comment: (Plutonium-)241 "on one warhead", as opposed to "on the other warhead".

Comment: on one warhead means?

Comment: The link you supply explains what '241' refers to. The sentence refers to the 241 _on one (particular) warhead_.

Comment: Is "one" necessary after "on"?

Comment: There were several warheads. One of them had some 241 missing. If there had been a single warhead, it would read "241 on *the* warhead..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, "241" means "Plutonium 241", a radioactive chemical (technically an isotope).

It's not plutonium **241 on one** warhead. It's **plutonium 241** on **one warhead**. It would be more accurate to say the plutonium **in** the warhead, but they chose to say **on**, for some reason.